# Spark dataframe is NULL (Invalid Tree)

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I have a spark (spark 2.1) job which processes the stream data using Kafka direct stream. I enriched the stream data with the data files stored in HDFS. I first read the data files(*.parquet) and stored them in a data frame, then enrich one record each time with this data frame.

The code ran without any error, but the enrichment did not occur. I ran the codes in debug mode and found the data frame (eg. df) is shown as an invalid tree. Why the data frame is null inside rdd.foreachPartition? how to correct this problem? Thanks!

```
 val kafkaSinkVar = ssc.sparkContext.broadcast(KafkaSink(kafkaServers, outputTopic))

 Service.aggregate(kafkaInputStream).foreachRDD(rdd => {  
      val df =ss.read.parquet( filePath + "/*.parquet" )
      println("Record Count in DF: " + df.count())  ==> the console shows the files were loaded successfully with the record count = 1300
      rdd.foreachPartition(partition => {
        val futures = partition.map(event => {
          sentMsgsNo.add(1L)
          val eventEnriched = someEnrichmen1(event,df)  ==> df is shown as invalid tree here
          kafkaSinkVar.value.sendCef(eventEnriched)
        })

        })
      })
    })
```